# Who are Sumukhi and Vidalakshi?

Tags: identification-request, goddess, kartikeya

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083138.html) of Agni Purana, it is mentiones about Kartikeya's image:-

> 27. (The image of) Skanda, the lord (of the universe) also known as Śākha and Viśākha, (is represented) as a boy possessing two arms and riding a peacock (with the images of) Sumukhī and Viḍālākṣī.

But, i was confused by Sumukhi & Vidalakshi with Devasena & Valli. So my question is:-

- Who are Sumukhi & Vidalakshi and Is they same as Devasena & Valli?
- What is their story & how they related to Lord Kartikeya?

Comment: As the name of the chapter suggests , it simply talks about  how the Godess/God should be represented in  a picture/sculpture (image form). Sumukhi and Bidalakshi must not mistaken for some seperate unknown deities, rather it should be interpreted as , consorts of Lord Subramanya should be represented in an image , as Good-faced(Su+mukhi) in the case of Godess Devasena, and (bidala+akshi cat eyed) while sculpting Godess Valli.